# SCSS interpolation error, trying to concatenate a percentage sign after a variable in a loop

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp

So this SCSS code works fine on my Macbook, but not my Ubuntu machine:

```
@each $distance, $color in $range-distances{

    @each $track in $tracks {
        .distance-slider--#{$distance}#{$track}{
            background: #{$color};
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #{$color} #{$distance}%, $grey 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
 [Task Failed [scss/_modules/input-range.scss
Error: Invalid CSS after "...} #{$distance}%": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ", $grey 0);"
        on line 101 of scss/_modules/input-range.scss
>> -gradient(to right, #{$color} #{$distance}%, $grey 0);
   ------------------------------------------^
```

There is nothing special going on in that task either:

```
gulp.task('sass', ['clean:styles'], function() {

  return gulp.src(paths.scssPath+'/site.scss')
  .pipe(plumber({ errorHandler: handleErrors }))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass({
    includePaths: [
      paths.bowerPath + '/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets',
      paths.bowerPath + '/components-font-awesome/scss',
      paths.scssGlob
    ],
    errLogToConsole: true,
    outputStyle: 'expanded'
  }))
  .pipe(postcss([
    autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 version'] })
  ]))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
  .pipe(gulp.dest( paths.cssCompiled ));
});
```

I am using the same gulp file, have installed my packages with the same package.json file (so all the dependency versions are the same), have the same version of gulp (3.9.1), but my node versions are different (4.2.1 on OSX and 4.4.4 on Ubuntu).

Should I be outputting those variables a different way or should I just try downgrading nodejs to 4.2.1?

Comment: So I don't know what the error is caused by or why I'm only experiencing it on Ubuntu and not OSX, but I solved it by changing `#{$distance}%` to `#{$distance+'%'}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I don't know why I would get that error on my Ubuntu machine and not my OSX machine, maybe its the node version. But I was able to fix it by changing the interpolation of #{$distance} to #{$distance+'%'}

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Had the same issue on my windows machine. I recently upgraded node from 4 for 5, it started happening to me after that.